# The definition of the right regular representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I'm having difficulties understanding the definition of the right regular representation as it appears in Dummit & Foote's Abstract Algebra text. On page 132 it says

> Let $\pi:G \to S_G$ be the left regular representation afforded by the action of $G$ on itself by left multiplication. For each $g \in G$ denote the permutation $\pi(g)$ by $\sigma_g$, so that $\sigma_g(x)=gx$ for all $x \in G$. Let $\lambda:G \to S_G$ be the permutation representation afforded by the corresponding right action of $G$ on itself, and for each $h \in G$ denote the permutation $\lambda(h)$ by $\tau_h$. Thus $\tau_h(x)=xh^{-1}$ for all $x \in G$ ($\lambda$ is called the *right regular representation* of $G$).

I can't make since of that definition. Earlier, on page 129 the authors explain exactly what is the right action corresponding to some given left action:

> For arbitrary group actions it is an easy exercise to check that if we are given a left group action of $G$ on $A$ then the map $A \times G \to A$ defined by $a \cdot g=g^{-1} \cdot a$ is a right group action. Conversely, given a right group action of $G$ on $A$ we can form a left group action by $g \cdot a=a \cdot g^{-1}$. Call these pairs *corresponding group actions*.

If I try to find the right group action corresponding to $g \cdot a=ga$, I get $a \cdot g:=g^{-1} \cdot a=g^{-1}a$. Hence it seems to me that the definition should be $\tau_h(x)=h^{-1}x$ and not $xh^{-1}$.

Are there any flaws with my reasoning?

Thanks!

Comment: $gG=G=Gg$, in first equality we see the permutation effect of $g$ as a left multiplication and in second equality we see the effect as an right multiplicatin. I think that is the main differences between right and left action. putting $g^{-1}$ etc has notational advantage, I guess.

Comment: @mesel while I make sense of your comment, I still can't see why the definition of the *right* regular representation involves multiplication on the right. If right actions are associated to left actions as the authors claim it doesn't seem right.

Comment: I think the word "corresponding" in the first quoted paragraph must be removed. There is no general way in which $\pi$ and $\lambda$ can be obtained one from another without knowing that we are acting on $G$ itself. You might want to point this out to Richard Foote ( http://www.cems.uvm.edu/~rfoote/ ), who lists the errata for the book on his webpage.

Answer (score 5):

In general, if $G$ acts on a set $S$ from the right via $(x,g) \mapsto x \cdot g$, then we obtain an action of $G$ on $S$ from the left via $g \cdot x := x \cdot g^{-1}$.

Let $*$ be the group multiplication in $G$. Then $G$ acts on $|G|$ (the underlying set of $G$, don't confuse it with $G$) from the right via $x \cdot g := x * g$. It follows that we obtain a left action from $G$ on $|G|$ via $g \cdot x :=  x \cdot g^{-1} = x * g^{-1}$. And this corresponds to a homomorphism of groups $G \to S(|G|)$ mapping $g$ to the permutation $(x \mapsto x * g^{-1}$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question remains unclear. The authors refer to $g \cdot x=x*g^{-1}$ as a *right* group action. How can this be the action corresponding to the one given by left multiplication?

Comment: @user1337 Wrong, the author (in the second blockquote of your question) quite plainly call $g\cdot x=x\cdot g^{-1}$ a **left** group action. Read it!

Comment: @blue I was referring to the first blockquote: "...afforded by the corresponding *right* action...".

Answer (score 2):

You seem to worry about these sentences:

> "Let $\lambda : G \to S_G$ be the permutation representation afforded by the corresponding
>   right action of $G$ on itself, and for each $h \in G$ denote the permutation $\lambda(h)$ by 
>   $\tau_h$. Thus $\tau_h(x)=xh^{−1}$ for all $x \in G$ ($\lambda$ is called the right regular representation of $G$)."

What you did at the end of your post is the following:
You considered the left group action of $G$ on itself by left multiplication.
Then you constructed the corresponding right group action and what you get is, correctly, $x \leftharpoonup h = h^{-1} x$.

The authors do something else in the above paragraph.
They first consider the right action of $G$ on itself by right multiplication, i.e. $x \leftharpoonup g := xg$.
But they want to obtain a "permutation representation", which they denote by $\lambda : G \to S_G$. 
Usually one wants this map to be a group homomorphism. In order to assure this, one needs to start with a *left* group action. 
What one can do is therefore the following: 
Consider the left group action of $G$ on itself corresponding to the above right group action of $G$ on itself by right multiplication. 
By your second quote this is given by $g \rightharpoonup x = x \leftharpoonup g^{-1} = x g^{-1}$. And this is exactly what the authors claim.

Comment: I'm sorry for not getting this, but in the blockquote I can't find any hints for a left action.

Comment: The point is that you want that the map $\lambda : G \to S_G$ to be a morphism of groups. Given an arbitrary left G-action on a set X, you get a morphism of groups $G \to S_X$ by sending $g$ to the map $X \to X, x \mapsto (g \rightharpoonup x)$. If however you have a right action of $G$ on $X$, then $G \to S_X, g \mapsto x \mapsto (x \leftharpoonup g)$ does not define a morphism of groups.